# Search and Sort Problem in JPA with list of entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Lets say I have two Entity, First One

```
//Annotations skipped
public class Person {
    List<Name> names;
    //getter,setter
}

public class Name {
     String name;
     //getter, setter
}
```

I want to search and sort according to name with JPA(Hibernate)

I write a query like;

```
SELECT entity FROM person entity LEFT JOIN entity.names as names
WHERE names.name like :keyword ORDER BY names.name
```

When there is one name in person there is no problem. Bu if more than one name exists JPA returns a Person for each name. If I use `Distict` this time, hibernate warns me to distinct must have order by part.

How can I solve this problem

Comment: you mean you want to order names  inside person class/entity?

Comment: no, I want to sort Person, based on names. let's assume Person1 has names name1, name2 and Person2 has names name3, name4. When I sort I want to Person1, Person2 in order.

Comment: why do you think you need a query for this. Rather just use Comparable and order your Person list in that case. Don't rely on queries for such tuning as DB is more costly resource.

Comment: @xxlali How do you compare two lists with elements in them?

Comment: Have updated my answer per your need please have a look.

Comment: I just given a simple example. I will have maybe 100 000 record and I will use pagination. I just don't want to sort items on java but on database. My criteria will be, concat names and sort based on this concatted names

Comment: **No-one** is going to want to page through 100,000 records.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you get all your persons in a list say `List<Person> persons` and then sort the list by using `Collections.sort(persons, customComparator);` where your `Comparator` implementation could be like below:

```
class CustomPersonComparator implements Comparator<Person>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return 0;//TODO for you: perform your names comparision here and return int comparison result accordingly.
    }
}
```

You can read about impl of comparator [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/)

Comment: my real model much more complicated. I used this example just for simplication

Comment: OP - here on this question your specific question is above how to get sorted names. In case you think your question needs more details please add those.  But current answer solves your stated problem.

Comment: Have updated my answer to meet your need. But please update your question to clearly state what you need.

Comment: I don't want to process this on jvm but on db.

Comment: you must be putting all your specific requirement in question so that people can help in right direction :).

Comment: Actually I think I did. But just you try to pull me another direction.